# Frustraiting How are there too many arguments in this if statement

Tags: if-statement

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        STATUS=$(cat $LOG.$i)
                if [ $STATUS != "$i-DOWN!" ]; then
                        echo "$(date): ping failed, $i host is down!" |
                        mail -s "$(date) $i host is down!" $EMAIL
                fi
        echo "$(date) $i-DOWN!" > $LOG.$i
else
        STATUS=$(cat $LOG.$i)
      **------->>>**if [ $STATUS != "$i-UP!" ]; then
                        echo "$(date): ping OK, $i host is up!" |
                        mail -s "$(date) $i host is up!" $EMAIL
                fi
        echo "$(date) $i-UP!" > $LOG.$i
fi
```

I keep getting the error "Too many arguments" for that specific line with teh arrow pointing to it..  but I have the exact same line above it and do not get the error...

This is frustrating anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$STATUS` contains spaces, try to wrap the expression in quotes:

```
if [ "$STATUS" != "$i-UP!" ]
```

The line above was not evaluated so it can't ever trigger an error. Note that shell scripts are not compiled and every line is evaluated only if it's reached at runtime.